# Zero crossing detection and full-wave rectifier for non-AC voltage

Tags: dc, rectifier, zero-crossing

Our control signal that ranges from -5 to 5 V needs to be split up such that the magnitude and sign can be send through different wires. So, for example, a -3 V input sends a 3 V signal through one wire, and a low signal through another, while a 3 V input sends a 3 V signal through one wire, and a high signal through another.

Researching solutions, I found zero crossing detection and full-wave rectifier do the job for AC current, but I can't tell if they function for DC current. Many implementations have features such as noise filters that require the signal to be AC. Are there already developed solutions for DC? An ideal solution would have as few components as possible.

Comment: How accurate does the output need to be across the range of input voltages? What happens around 0 volts when the circuit is likely producing nominally 0 volts but a flickering logic level due to noise?

Comment: The magnitude input needs to be quite precise. Around 0 volt is the sign flickering not too much an issue, since there is a minimum volt magnitude required.

Comment: Numbers are needed and not meaningless words like "quite precise". I believe you mean the magnitude of the output btw. You say non-AC but, how fast does the signal change in amplitude i.e. what bandwidth does it have?

Comment: I used "quite precise" because I don't have access to the required numbers on that front. I expect a noise ratio of 1% is too high. The signal switches sign with low (depending on which program runs) frequency, but the sign switch has to be determined with a 1000 Hz precision

Comment: At the risk of starting so sound like Tony, all good designs for production start with specification on what's needed to be solved.

Answer (score 5):

A precision full-wave active rectifier circuit usually takes 2 opamps, and will give you an output that is the absolute value of the input.  A comparator circuit usually takes one opamp, and will give you a logic level related to the sign.  Both of these are DC-coupled circuits, and will work down to 0 Hz.

As Andy said, a problem will be input signal noise causing the output of the comparator to bounce around at low signal levels.  An input lowpass filter can remove some of the noise while maintaining the DC value of the input, but it also introduces a time delay (phase shift) between its input and output.  This will increase the system's settling time.  The most simple filter is one R and one C.  For better filtering, opamps are needed.

What is the maximum frequency component of interest, or maximum rate of change of the input signal?

UPDATE:

Kuba's upper circuit: The phase-split-and-mux approach is one of those things I knew a while ago, but never used and forgot about.  Nice reminder.

Kuba's lower circuit: The switched-gain approach is another old trick that never got enough recognition.  The 4066 analog switch probably can be replaced with a single n-channel, logic-level MOSFET, for a smaller and more simple solution.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The signal in question will be updated at 1000 Hz.

Answer (score 4):

> Our control signal that ranges from -5 volt to 5 volt needs to be split up

Why? I smell an XY problem.

If you really need to do this, then a comparator with small hysteresis, selecting the output from a +1 and a -1 buffer, will do it with little fuss.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRQJ2x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Another option is to use a circuit with a switchable +1/-1 gain:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzL5iU.png)</sup>

In both cases, OA1 is optional to buffer the input voltage. If the input is sourced from a relatively low-impedance node, it perhaps is unnecessary.

The OA4 cable driver, as well as the sign buffer, are both necessary to prevent the cable load from distorting the output.

R5 can be increased to make the hysteresis deadband around 0V wider. CMP1 must be a comparator with push-pull output, powered from same supplies as the op-amps. The comparator output fed to MUX1 and BUF1 needs to be scaled to whatever logic level the buffer and the MUX accept - likely 0V..3V.

Comment: Thank you for drawing up these circuits. During my research online I came across many similar diagrams. The fact that you also went for this seems to say that there are no pre built solutions (off the shelve, in a single chip, I don't know the right lingo.) Is that correct?

Comment: @9sven6 That's correct. You still should edit the question and explain why is this weird absolute value + sign transmission needed. It's not very practical, and if the signal has to swing around zero, whatever is receiving the signal will have trouble and there will be crossover distortion. If you need to transmit +/-5V signal in unipolar fashion, just squeeze (map) it onto the 0..3V range. I.e. -5V maps to 0V, and +5V maps to +3V, linearly. That will retain the signal integrity and can be fed directly into a unipolar ADC input. Sign bit won't work as a "free bit of resolution" for the ADC.

Comment: If your idea was to use this circuit to get a "free ADC bit", then unfortunately it's not the way to go unless the circuit's precision would be much improved, and that would potentially take a bit more sophisticated of a circuit. In most likelihood, you'd need an intelligent ADC-DAC that can generate the sign and absolute value signals digitally, minimizing errors (distortion). TI has just come out with intelligent ADC/DAC IIRC, those would probably do the job.

Comment: You should probably still look at intelligent ADC/DAC chips, since those can do the range mapping you need, I'd imagine, with good performance. They integrate some digital logic needed to do the mappings, so an MCU is not necessary for operation.